# Invalid prop `verseObj.version_id` of type `string` supplied to `VerseForm`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm making a public prayer journal where you can also add verses in full stack. Whenever the form renders, I get the error above. No clue why, considering create was working a few days ago, and I haven't messed with it.

VerseForm.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getVersions().then(setVersions);
    if (verseObj.id) {
      getSingleVerse(verseObj.id).then((response) => {
        setCurrentVerse(response);
        // setSelectedVersion(verseObj.version_id.id);
      });
    }
  }, [verseObj]);

  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (verseObj.id) {
      updateVerse(user, currentVerse, verseObj.id)
        .then(() => router.push('/'));
    } else {
      const payload = { ...currentVerse };
      createVerse(payload, user).then(setCurrentVerse(initialState));
    }
  };


VerseForm.propTypes = {
  verseObj: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    verse: PropTypes.string,
    content: PropTypes.string,
    version_id: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
      label: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }),
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    uid: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.number,
  }).isRequired,
};

VerseForm.defaultProps = {
  verseObj: initialState,
};
```

Comment: add the useState  where you have this : **setSelectedVersion**

Comment: Where's the rest of the code for your component? The error you get basically says that you pass to props verseObj.version_id as string, but in your propTypes it's defined as object of specified shape. Please, provide rest of the component code for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part wasn't in the question, but i had to change version_id from a string to this in initialState:

```
`version_id: {
    id: 0,
    label: '',
  },`
```